# Is there a metric projection that works everywhere in the world? If not, what's the smallest set of EPSG codes for that?

Tags: coordinate-system, rgeos

I'm doing some calculations per country, using `rgeos` library in R. For each country, I need to calculate the bounding box area. So I transform the country's bounding box in a `sp` object, project it into an UTM coordinate system, and finally calculate the area:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
wb <- readOGR('.','WorldBorders')
for (i in 1:nrow(wb)) {
    bb <- bbox2SP(bbox=bbox(wb[i,]))
    bb <- spTransform(bb,CRS('+init=epsg:31998'))
    gArea(bb) # use this value somewhere
}
```

Only after Ethiopia has given an error, I noticed that EPSG 31998 is only to South America. However, my code worked for countries even farther, such as Afghanistan, Australia, China...

The error may be repeated following this steps:

```
bb <- bbox2SP(14.88361,3.406389,32.991104,47.98824)
bb <- spTransform(bb,CRS('+init=epsg:31998'))

non finite transformation detected:
[1] 47.988240  3.406389       Inf       Inf
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Polygons 1 Polygon 1 points 4
In addition: Warning message:
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
  1 projected point(s) not finite
```

So my question is: is there any EPSG code that I can use anywhere in the world to calculate area in meters? Or will I have to use different codes in different places? In this case, what is the minimum set of EPSG codes that should I use?

Comment: "EPSG 31998 is only to South America" - not quite right, UTM Zones are only 6 degrees (mostly, there are a handful of exceptions) wide and are different between N & S hemisphere.  EPSG 31998 is only used for South America *between 48°W and 42°W in the southern hemisphere*. Suggest you research geodesic area (something like [`geosphere`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=geosphere) which has a `areaPolygon` function to calculate geodesic area, but I don't use R so have no idea if this is a good choice or not).

Comment: @user2856 Yeah, I know UTM zones are only 6 degrees wide, but for this kind of calculation it works for South America as a whole (as I said, it worked for many different countries in all continents, with enough precision for my function to work... up to Ethiopia [?]). Your solution seem to work enough for me. With the default parameters, it found an area of Brazilian bounding box that is 98.46% of that calculated by rgeos' `gArea()`. That fits my purpose right now. Thank you! You may want to add that as an answer.

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no projected coordinate system that works for the whole globe to calculate lengths and areas but you can use the centre of your geographic box to find the zone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude therefore the EPSG is 32600 + zone if north of the equator and 32700 if you're south of the equator, this will extend your code by no more than a few lines. The other option is geodesic distance/area https://proj.org/geodesic.html which will work anywhere but would need a complete rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you! I'll take a look at it. You may want to add that as an answer.

Comment: Consider saving your data into PostGIS as geography features https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html

Comment: EPSG doesn't have a set of equal area projCRS that cover the world yet (I have an action item to make recommendations). For areas, an ellipsoid-based projCRS is fine--the results are affected more by the point density of the feature.

Comment: @user30184 Too much work for a single job. Thank you!

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you! I guess "ellipsoid-based projCRS" is what `areaPolygon` uses (suggest by user2856)? It worked for me.

Comment: There are a lot of equal area projections that support spheres only like some Eckerts. That's what I was thinking of but didn't say it clearly.

Comment: @mkennedy [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/?q=eckert) have two groups of Eckert (World and Sphere), but it doesn't explain them. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area) apparently only talks about Eckert II, IV and VI. A full summary would be nice.

Comment: Those come from Esri and are badly named (by me! a long time ago). "World" means that the semimajor axis of WGS84 is used for the radius while "Sphere" uses an authalic sphere's radius (authalic sphere = sphere of same surface area as ellipsoid it's based upon).

Comment: This is only Esri-supported projections, but you can find out more about them [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/list-of-supported-map-projections.htm). All added/updated within the last year.